# Is it possible for Alexa to wait in a skill without directly awaiting user input?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I realize the question may be badly phrased, but that is the best I could come up with.

My issue is that I use Alexa in a scenario where I sporadically give an Alexa skill commands (say every few minutes), and I don't want to have to re-invoke that skill every time.

Currently, after I give a command, Alexa replies that she is performing that action, but at the end she expects new user input via:

```
this.emit(':responseReady');
```

However, that isn't quite what I want, since most of the time I don't immediately want to give another command. Instead, a few minutes later, I will want to interact with that skill again.

If I completely exit the skill, though, I will have to re-invoke it next time, and get the whole skill welcome message again ("Welcome to *skill name*. You can say..."). I don't see that as optimal either.

Is there a way to keep that skill "open/active" so that the next command I give is interpreted in the context of that skill, without having to emit :responseReady (which expects an immediate response) and without having to relaunch the skill ("Alexa, open *skill name*")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in a hacky way by enabling streaming audio in your skill. Essentially, you would give your response then tack on a silent (or not silent) audio track to keep your skill open.

The user will need to give the wake word to interrupt the audio and you will need to say the next thing before the audio runs out, otherwise you will need to open the skill again.

Enabling audio does come with some caveats, in particular you need to handle all of the associated built in intents. See
 https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx1DSINBM8LUNHY/New-Alexa-Skills-Kit-ASK-Feature-Audio-Streaming-in-Alexa-Skills

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll definitely look into this. Do you happen to know, off the top of your head, if there is a maximum duration for the audio that can be played? If not, I'll look it up.

Comment: Not sure, but there are skills that play podcasts, which can run for a while.

Comment: I think this is exactly how Find My Phone skill is doing. To pair it with your phone it first sends a text message, then it says: "When you receive a code say 'Alexa, and then your code number'". Then it starts streaming silent music. When you say "Alexa, <code>" it activates skill intent.

Answer (score 6):

I figured out the most simple way to wait for a user response. In your reply you can add some silent audio. User can always interrupt this by saying "Alexa, [intent]", which will trigger a specific intent for your app.

You need to know that an audio should be less than 90 seconds. I used 80 seconds mp3. Grouping multiple audios in one reply does not help. The best you can do is to emit two replies, which will give you about 160 seconds of waiting time.

Here is an example code that I use in my skill:

```
    // Get silence to wait for a user input.
    var silence = '<audio src="' + PATHS.SILENCE_80_SEC + '" />';
    var reply = 'Please go to <emphasis level="moderate">www.plumhead.xyz/pair</emphasis> and tell me your unique pairing code. Again, go to <emphasis level="moderate">www.plumhead.xyz/pair</emphasis> to get a pairing code. When you are ready say: "Alexa, and your pairing code".' + silence;
    alexa.emit(':ask', reply, reply);
```

To generate silent mp3 for Alexa you can use `ffmpeg`. Next commands generate 80 seconds mp3 and then convert it to the format that Alexa can accept:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=mono -t 80 -q:a 9 -acodec libmp3lame out.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i out.mp3 -ar 16000 -ab 48k -codec:a libmp3lame -ac 1  silence-80-sec.mp3
```

Answer (score 2):

Keeping your skill open infinitely is not supported now and I do not think it will ever be supported in the future due to the security concerns involved in allowing a skill to listen in on the user all the time.

But, if your problem is "user getting the whole welcome message again on coming back to the skill", you can build a better experience by maintaining the last performed action of the user in a database. You can use the user id that is sent as part of the request to identify each user. So the next time an user comes back to the skill, you can use the database to identify the context and provide an appropriate response. And of course to make this work you will need to update the database for each action performed by the user.

In nodejs you will get the user id value in `this.event.session.user.userId`.

Here is a sample code snippet to showcase the welcome message logic,

```
"LaunchRequest": function () {
        var userId = this.event.session.user.userId;
        dbHelper.getUser(userId, function (response) {
            if (response && response.lastPerformedAction) {
                //respond based on context
            }
            else {
                //respond with usual welcome message
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't Alexa always have to show an indicator when a skill is listening to you (blue ring)? Wouldn't that avoid the security concern? Thanks for the tip regarding the DB. The only issue I have with that, is that I do want the welcome message to play when the user first starts using the skill (per "session". If it always persists the last command, the user will only ever get the welcome message once (the first time they open the skill). Subsequently they will always get contextual responses, even from a "session" from a week ago, which wouldn't be relevant any more.

Comment: @NikWeiss Yes, it will show an indicator while listening. But if the user does not notice the indicator or forgets to exit, a malicious skill may listen in on the user infinitely which is a serious privacy concern. Currently alexa will listen for 8 seconds max for user input. Another issue with allowing a skill to listen more than 8 seconds is how long can one skill be allowed to listen? and how to handle when multiple skills want to listen infinitely?

Comment: @NikWeiss You can store the timestamp while updating the last performed action in the database and use it to decide if the last action will still remain relevant now.